# Dynamically created TabItems w/ MultiBinding and RelativeSource -> UnsetValue

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic, tabitem, multibinding

In my WPF application I want to create TabItems dynamically within a reusable UserControl containing a TabControl.

The TabControl's ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection instance via standard DataBinding.

I create the Tab items like this **AFTER** `InitializeComponent()` has been called!

```
// ...
int itemCount = 0;
TabItem it = null;

it = new TabItem();
it.Header = "Sicherungen + Relais";
tabItemList.Insert(itemCount++, it);            

it = new TabItem();
it.Header = "Lage der Bauteile";
tabItemList.Insert(itemCount++, it);

it = new TabItem();
it.Header = "Schaltpläne";
tabItemList.Insert(itemCount++, it);

it = new TabItem();
it.Header = "Tipps + Tricks";
tabItemList.Insert(itemCount++, it);
```

The good news is, that the items are indeed added to the TabControl w/ their respective headers.

The problem now occurs, when WPF is attempting to apply a style to them AFTER the Window has become Visible!

I have this default style for the TabItems:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource TISTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Width">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource convCategoryTabWidthConverter}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}"
                         Path="ActualWidth" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the converter:

```
public class CategoryTabWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Count() < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Values array passed is invalid.", "values");

        if(values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            return 0; // Added for breakpoint. Bailing out here!!!
        }

        TabControl tabCtrl = values[0] as TabControl;
        Double w = (tabCtrl.ActualWidth / tabCtrl.Items.Count);
        w = (w <= 1) ? 0.0 : (w - 1);
        return w;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Remarks:** I'm using this converter and style in two other places, where the TabItems are statically added in XAML! In these cases it all works fine!

When the TabItems are added dynamically however, both, the TabControl RelativeSource and its ActualWidth evaluate to `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

I expect some logic errors I encountered here.

When are styles applied? Before TabItems are properly added to the internal trees or after?
Does anybody have ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

I'll investigate further and thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself. The problem was that i forgot that the ItemsSource's elements will be wrapped into TabItem instance.

A TabItem within a TabItem doesn't really make sense.

Directly inserting them into TabControl.Items made it work surprisingly.